# How reference a variable in Service on a local variable on component from a Angular Project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a UserService that when my user signs on my application, I populate it with the data from the user to show in all my components.

But I'm facing a little problem When I reference the object like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userModel = this.userService.getUserModel();
 }
```

He works fine for the first load, but I have a page that changing the user data and I want to be reflected for all my application, so when I change this object **this.userModel**, the changes don't reflect all my components is like just a copy from the object from Service.

The solution that I make is Putting this object directly in my HTML files **this.userService.getUserModel()** but it is too large and I want to avoid that, just for a good syntax.

The question is how I can make a real reference to this variable without putting this service method directly on my components.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use observable, then subscribe to it.

For example:

```
public function getUserModel(): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.apiService.getUser(); // This is an observable
}
```

Then on your component, instead of doing this:

```
this.userModel = this.userService.getUserModel();
```

You should instead do this:

```
this.userService.getUserModel().pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy$)).subscribe(user => {
    this.userModel = user;
}
```

**Pointers**

this._onDestroy$ is a really easy way to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed, helps minimize memory leaks.

So you can add:

```
private _onDestroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Then in your **ngOnDestroy**

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy$.next();
    this._onDestroy$.complete();
}
```

So, this should update the value in your HTML automatically.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EventEmitter that emits the userModel every time it changes. And then, eu get that observable on the classes that you want to be notified, and subscribe to the changes. Like this.

```js
class UserService {
  userModelEvent: EventEmitter<UserModel> = new EventEmitter();
}

class AnotherClass {
  userModel: UserModel;

  constructor(userService: UserService) {}

  onInit() {
    this.userService.userModelEvent.subscribe(userModel => this.userModel = userModel);
  }
}
```